# Uncaught exception on importing XML product list to Prestashop

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

Hi I am just new and starting up. My requirement was to import XML product list to Prestashop as products. Thankfully there is already a sample documentation on the same provided in the documentation of prestashop. I just copy pasted and tried it out. Sadly it doesn't worked well. I will copy paste the code I tried below and the error message after that.

PHP File (located in the root directory of prestashop):

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php');

$xml_string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <Products>
    <Reference>1101TEST</Reference>
    <Valid_internet_product>1</Valid_internet_product>
    <Products_name>Test product</Products_name>
    <Price>49.99</Price>
    <Active_product>1</Active_product>
    <SupplierNo>8</SupplierNo>
    <Weight>5</Weight>
    <Description>My long product description</Description>
    <Short_Description>Product desc.</Short_Description>
    <MinOrderQty>1</MinOrderQty>
    <Categories>
      <Category>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
          <CategoryName>Home\Prod</CategoryName>
          <Active_category>1</Active_category>
          <Changed>0</Changed>
      </Category>
    </Categories>
    <Tax_Class_ID>1</Tax_Class_ID>
    <Discount>
      <Discount_percentage>percentage</Discount_percentage>
      <discountprice_ex_vat>0</discountprice_ex_vat>
      <Discountprice_include_vat>0</Discountprice_include_vat>
      <Pct_ReductionPercent>0</Pct_ReductionPercent>
    </Discount>
  </Products>
</Document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach ($xml->Products as $product_xml)
{
    if ($product_xml->Valid_internet_product == 1)
    {
        /* Update an existing product or Create a new one */
        $id_product = (int)Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE reference = \''.pSQL($product_xml->Reference).'\'');
        $product = $id_product ? new Product((int)$id_product, true) : new Product();
        $product->reference = $product_xml->Reference;
        $product->price = (float)$product_xml->Price;
        $product->active = (int)$product_xml->Active_product;
        $product->weight = (float)$product_xml->Weight;
        $product->minimal_quantity = (int)$product_xml->MinOrderQty;
        $product->id_category_default = 2;
        $product->name[1] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Products_name);
        $product->description[1] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Description);
        $product->description_short[1] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Short_Description);
        $product->link_rewrite[1] = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->Products_name);
        if (!isset($product->date_add) || empty($product->date_add))
            $product->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $product->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id_product ? $product->updateCategories(array(2)) : $product->addToCategories(array(2));
        $product->save();

        echo 'Product <b>'.$product->name[1].'</b> '.($id_product ? 'updated' : 'created').'<br />';
    }
}
```

Error message is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopException' with message 'Property Product->link_rewrite is empty'
```

I tried to var_dump $product->link_rewrite[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Tsp.png) inside the loop  and it does have string "test-product".

What I am missing ?

Screenshot of complete error message :
[image]

Comment: Check if in your shop are installed other languages, usually for the multilingual fields prestashop use an array with index equal to ID language. So try to do this: $product->link_rewrite = [...]

Comment: Hi @SarcoM, My store have two languages installed English US (Disabled, ID :1) and English UK (Enabled, ID : 2). Can you tell me what should I modify in the above snippet to get this working ?

Comment: Try the solution that I wrote :)

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, in this case seeing that you have two languages installed, you have to set the link rewrite for all languages:

Make this changes:

```
$languages = Language::getLanguages(true); // Get all the active languages
foreach(...){
    /* ... */

    /* change '$product->link[1] = ...' in this */
    foreach($languages as $language)
    {
        $product->name[$language['id_lang']] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Products_name);
        $product->description[$language['id_lang']] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Description);
        $product->description_short[$language['id_lang']] = utf8_encode($product_xml->Short_Description);
        $product->link[$language['id_lang']] = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->Products_name);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

You can't know the exactly ID of your language that prestashop have saved, so this is the right method to save the multilingual fields.

Specifically in your case, you have to set 2 for the index of array, because your language have ID 2, the language with ID 1 is disabled, so it's "useless" and you must give at least the field for the default language.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have tried trying setting the array index to [2] after reading your first reply. Sadly it didn't worked. This one also the same. Not working. Throwing almost same error. PS (Commenting out the validation part in the prestashop core file makes things working ;). Data is inserted and everything is fine)

Comment: Know that comment out the validation it's not final a solution, nay, it's not a solution. :).

Comment: One more thing is that the above code is working without a single error on Prestashop 1.6+